# In awk, is there a functional difference between putting conditions outside the brackets or inside?

Tags: awk

As far as I can tell, this:

```
$2 > 50{print}
```

functions exactly the same way as this:

```
{if ($2 > 50) print}
```

When should I use one vs the other, or is it a matter of style?

Answer (score 2):

2nd one is much more readable in my opinion (especially for non awk gurus who may have to maintain you code).

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly style. The first example is canonical AWK. There are, of course, times when an `if` statement is required.

Consider that:

```
$2 > 50 {foo; print}
```

takes 20 characters versus 27 for the following:

```
{if ($2 > 50) {foo; print}}
```

If you remove spaces, it would be 16 versus 22 characters.

So the former is more desirable if you are interested in economy (both in terms of actual characters and visually).

As potong points out, the `if` form requires curly braces if there are more than one statement (as I have shown in my second example above). If there is only one statement, they are optional. This is the source of subtle bugs if it's written without and additional statements are later added without adding braces. Also, for the reader of a script, the intent is much clearer if the braces are included.

Comment: *ecomony* isn't even a consideration, and a false argument

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Economy can aid in readability, as can using canonical forms. These are not *always* the case, but they are important considerations. You will notice that my last sentence includes the word "if".

Comment: You could also point out that to add statements to `{if ($2 > 50) print}` one must add surrounding curly braces `{...}` and that a novice may miss this fact and introduce a *bug* into their code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same. As with most syntax alternatives, there are trade offs.

I mostly agree with John3136 that 2nd form has a higher likelyhood of being understood by someone with background in c, c++, C#, java, and others.

And as Dennis Williamson points out, there are times you have to use the `if (...)` form.

For one-lines, I think the first form is useful, acceptable, and helps reinforce the primary design of awk, i.e. [pattern]-[action] (being optional or providing a default behaviour).

If you look at comp.lang.awk, you'll see that the long-timers mostly prefer style 1.

Large blocks of code in style 1, to my eye, are difficult to read, but do have the look of lex code.

So.... depends ;-) .... are you writing code that will ultimately be maintained by likely non-awk experts? Then stick w style 2. Writing for  yourself? Use both so you don't get rusty!

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are the same.

On the first form, you can omit `{ print }` because it's the default action. So, that works too:

```
$2 > 50
```